# Handling a gesture that needs to address multiple selectors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

Im dealing with some very confusing code on a project, it seems a gesture was used to trigger a func, and that func fires off a selector to a parent view the trigger a func, this is working fine after some tweaks.

Issue is, the subclass is used in a couple of different parent views, so using superview to find a selector is causing a crash, it exists in 1 use, but not in the second.

How can i handle this so that it calls different selectors based on its parent view? The current setup seems pretty hacky and obviously doesnt work as it needs to... some code below:

The reused view inits with this gesture:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bandBypassWasPressed:)];
        [tap setDelegate:self];
        [tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Calling this func in its self:

```
- (IBAction)bandBypassWasPressed:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, [sender locationInView:self])) {
            [self.superview performSelector:@selector(bandViewOn:) withObject:self];
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        }
    }
```

The issue is that 'bandViewOn' only exists in the superview in 1 use of this subview, not in the other, meaning it fires off a call and crashes the app as there isnt a func there with that name.

There is a different func I want it to call depending on its superview. This is

```
- (void)lowBandBypass:(NSInteger)on {
        NSLog(@"lowBandBypass CALLED");
        _eqData.filter[1].bypass = on;
        _lowBand.on = on;
        [_lowBand setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

How can i handle this to resolve this odd issue...

Cheers and appreciate its a bit complex!

Comment: maybe before call perfromSelector, you should check if your superView respondsToSelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [respondsToSelector](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector) to check that the superview implements the method before calling it.

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, [sender locationInView:self])) {
    if [self.superview respondsToSelector:@selector(bandViewOn:)] {
        [self.superview performSelector:@selector(bandViewOn:) withObject:self];
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```